# How to convert an array to multiple columns in big query

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I am trying to sort out how to change this array so that it shows the returned values across multiple columns instead of together.

```
SELECT
handle,
fdc.identifiers
FROM table.fdc
```

Code returns the following

| Handle | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3123 |
|  | 1233 |
|  | 1232 |
| 3456 | 1231 |
|  | 3411 |
| 2321 |  |
| 1235 |  |

The code returns all of the identifiers in one column.  Can they be split out to multiple columns?

I would like the table to look like this below:

| Handle | Identifier |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 3123 | 1233 | 1232 |
| 3456 | 1231 | 3411 |  |
| 2321 |  |  |  |
| 1235 |  |  |  |

The code returns all of the identifiers in one column.  Can they be split out to multiple columns?

Comment: Can you post an example of what the output table should look like?

Comment: Edited the post with a new table to demonstrate what I need.  Each Handle can have a unique amount of identifiers or be null.  The extra columns can be labeled if needed.

Comment: If the number of identifiers is indeterminate it might make more sense to return them in an ARRAY column. See this answer by Mikhail Berlyant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110942/15921941

Comment: The results are already in an array, so any type of array_agg function doesn't work.   Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select handle, val, offset
  from your_table t
  left join t.identifiers val with offset
)
pivot (min(val) as identifier for offset in (0, 1, 2))
```

if to apply to dummy data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 1234 handle, [3123, 1233, 1232] identifiers union all
  select 3456, [1231, 3411] union all
  select 2321, [] union all 
  select 1235, []
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help!  I literally have 0 understanding of what's going on in your code.  any chance you can explain it?  specifically with offset and pivot, never used them before.  I also need to have a where clause that specifies a date range.  I tried to add that to the code and it couldn't recognize any date range no matter how I labeled anything.